# Why is JGroups on Android using IPv6 to connect?

Tags: android, jgroups

From an Android device, I'm attempting to set up a tunnel to a Gossip router on the local network. I'm using this as the config:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/JGroups-3.4.xsd">
    <TUNNEL gossip_router_hosts="${jgroups.tunnel.gossip_router_hosts:10.20.30.152[12001]}"/>
</config>
```

With code like this:

```
channel = JChannel(context.getAssets().open("jgroups.xml"))
channel.setReceiver(this)
channel.connect("MyGroup")
```

However, the app is attempting to connect via IPv6 by default, which doesn't appear to be working:

```
20096:connect(41, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(12001), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:10.20.30.152", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

This occurs even when I remove any IPv6 addresses from the network interface. I understand that there is a JVM flag for favoring IPv4, but I believe this is not applicable to Android. Setting options via `adb` isn't going to be a good solution either.

Is there another way to force JGroups to use IPv4 for connecting? Or is there some other route to a fix?

I've tested this on Android 8.0 and see the behavior with JGroups versions 4.1.6 and 3.6.19.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird config! Are you sure, you want to have a protocol stack with *only* TUNNEL in it?

If so, then I guess `gossip_router_hosts` needs to point to an IPv6 address.

Comment: The [original config](https://gist.github.com/allenluce/6c5b71b08dbbdd8ac3cb7cc76cc9ce0f) is a bit larger. Is there a recommended config for this? IPv6 address doesn't work in this case as there's no local IPv6 infrastructure.

Comment: My goal here is to get two devices communicating when multicast doesn't work between them.